# how to debug in other window desktop device

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows

i'm making windows app works like kiosk with serial port with card reader, printer and barcode reader.
I had a experience with ios and android application but it is my first time to make windows app.
Building and debug windows app in local has no problem. However, making a serial port code was a problem, i thought it will be similar with other phones like just connect the phone and run it but connecting the window device was not.
try to connect with usb, but cant see in avalable devices.

i was planing to make the code(like response code and return code) while looking debug log.

is there any way to debug like which we do debuging like android or IOS.

Or is there other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps:

- Found the app.so file in **`..\build\windows`**
- Copied the file and pasted it in **`..\build\windows\runner\Debug\data`**

Original [Source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/97086#issuecomment-1029963716)